# Not able to successfully deploy a c# winforms application to other computers

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, installation

I have my C# winforms application that I have built and I can't figure out how to deploy it to other machines.

In a perfect world I think I should be able to do a release build and then take the release folder, zip it up and send it to whomever I wish. Not so. I've tried click once but none of the options that are listed for the delivery method fit into the category of what I want (being able to get a folder and then to send it to someone).

I've seen plenty of tutorials but they are all either from installing the program via a url or removable media or just not about a winforms app all together.

Someone please help.....

Comment: How exactly does it fail on those other computers?  Is the target architecture different?

Comment: what errors or such do you get?

Comment: You can still do what you described. Just copy the release folder in the bin directory. Unless you have other dependencies that must be met.

Comment: Setting all references of your application to copy local = true should copy all you need to your bin directory.

Comment: Copying your rep and all the needed dll is actually sufficient :) 
Are you sure you have not left an hardcoded path in your code ? This happens a lot and creates almost immediate bugs when trying to start it from a different computer !

Comment: I don't get any errors when I try to run the .exe on other computers. The only thing that comes up is a warning saying that this program may be unsafe and asks if I'm sure that I want to run the program or not.

Answer (score 2):

**Every win application** has a **'bin'** folder, And in this folder there are some files , you can use that **.exe** file which has been **created by c#** but if you are using some .dll files or etc that you added to your own application you should copy them too.
So now you know where the **.exe** file is and what files else you should copy with that too, make a zip file with them and they are executable on other windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy very easily to other computers with Clickonce. Clickonce can be used for both online and offline.

Make a empty folder named formapp in let's say c:₩.
Right-click on your project in solution explorer and click property. Click publish and write c:₩formapp into 2 inputboxes samely. And click publish.

And you can also use publish wizard on the left of publish button.

If the publish is done successfully, you can find the folder is full of files.
You can copy the folder and paste and run in other computers.

Hope this helps..

Comment: I tried to use clickonce as outlined above and when I try to install the program on another computer it just gives me a generic error saying that the application couldn't be installed.